# Can't boot into Ubuntu 18.04, blinking cursor

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, nvidia, uefi

I tried to boot into my Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using a desktop computer with an ASUS P5NA7 motherboard and a Q6600 CPU with integrated NVIDIA graphics.

When using `text` instead of `splash silent`, the computer freezes at a specific stage.

I tried to fiddle with the different options of `nomodeset`, `acpi` and `apic`. I even used an Ubuntu live USB trying to boot into the *Try Ubuntu before installing* option, but it didn't work.

Here is what I got when I tried to boot with `text` option in GRUB:

[image]

Disabled ACPI in BIOS:

[image]

Attempted to boot Live USB with `acpi` off:

[image]

Attempted to boot live USB with `acpi` off, `nomodeset` and `noapic`:

[image]

I didn't do an update before this failure to boot. Today I tried the following steps that all failed:

- Boot with all older kernels.
- Boot live USB to try to install Ubuntu.
- Boot live USB to single user mode.
- Boot secondary FreeBSD installation (fails on an amazingly similar error).
- Boot Windows 7 from another multi-boot.
- Boot Boot-Repair live USB.

I can’t reinstall even if I wanted to, since selecting that option from the live USB didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had installed an ATEN 2-port USB kvm switch for my keyboard / mouse earlier. Removing it solves the issue.